# Connecting to WMS in QGIS - Single Band Image Won't Render as TIFF?

Tags: wms, geotiff-tiff, image-service

In QGIS when we connect to an ArcGIS Image Service via WMS we can load the data as PNG/JPEG, however TIFFs do not render on the map.

It is only occurring with single band Image Services, the 3-band services are able to render as TIFFs through WMS.

What could be the problem?
All services have the same WMS capabilities enabled.

Can a TIFF not render a single-band 32-bit floating point dataset in WMS?